# Updating table with child table values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 table: `CRM_Inquiries` and `ICS_Subscribers`.  CRM_Inquiries has the primary key `InquiryID` and a foreign key, `SubID` to associate the table to `ICS_Subscribers` as well as `Fname` and `Lname`. ICS_Subscribers has the primary key `SubID` and the columns `SubFirstName` and `SubLastName`. I need to run a query to retrieve CRM_Inquiry rows and update the Fname and Lname values with the SubFirstName and SubLastName in the ICS_Subscriber table. I hope that makes sense..

I wrote a script to accomplish this but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it.

```
CREATE TABLE #inq(
InquiryID INT,
SubID INT
)

INSERT INTO #inq 
SELECT DISTINCT InquiryID, SUbId 
FROM CRM_Inquiries 
WHERE LName = 'Poe' AND SubID IS NOT NULL


DECLARE @totalCount INT
SELECT @totalCount = COUNT(*) FROM #inq 

PRINT @totalCount

WHILE(@totalCount > 0)
BEGIN

DECLARE @subId varchar(250)
DECLARE @inquiryID INT

SELECT TOP 1 @subId = subID, @inquiryID = inquiryID FROM #inq

PRINT 'SubID = ' + @subID
PRINT 'InquiryID= ' + CAST(@inquiryId AS VARCHAR(MAX))

UPDATE CRM_Inquiries 
SET FName = (SELECT SubFirstName FROM ICS_Subscribers WHERE SubID = @subId),
LName = (SELECT SubLastName FROM ICS_Subscribers WHERE SubID = @subId)
WHERE InquiryID = @inquiryID

DELETE FROM #inq WHERE InquiryID = @inquiryID


SELECT @totalCount = COUNT(*) FROM #inq 
PRINT @totalCount
END


DROP TABLE #inq
```

The LName='Poe' is completely arbitrary, I have a much more complex query but for the sake of the example I just created that.